# Python3.6.2 install package cause error

Tags: python

python:3.6.2

create virtual environment:

```
python -m venv venv
```

install package:

```
pip install flask
```

cause exception:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\locations.py", line 141, in distutils_scheme
    d.parse_config_files()
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 395, in parse_config_files
    parser.read(filename)
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "d:\python36-32\lib\configparser.py", line 1015, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: incomplete multibyte sequence
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What does sys.getdefaultencoding() say?

Comment: @saul it's utf8

Comment: I've seen that before when someone had an older `pip` version and international characters in the path he worked in.

Comment: @KlausD. I solved it as below.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove a file in my project and pip works fine again. Very strange!

The file is setup.cfg. According to flask [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/distribute/#tagging-builds)

```
[egg_info] tag_build = .dev tag_date = 1

[aliases] release = egg_info -RDb ”
```

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2429 on Flask's GitHub.